# Is it okay to push registers purely for preservation for short periods of time?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I have been learning NASM for a few weeks now. All is going well - I have been focusing on 64-bit for now.

Earlier I noticed that the `rdx` register was being messed with when I execute a `mul` instruction.

Basically, the code was similar to this:

```
; Code using RDX is up here

mov rax,2
mov rbx,10

mul rbx

; Code using RDX again is down here .. but the value is now zero
```

So, obviously RDX has something to do with `mul`. To fix this, I changed the code to this:

```
push rdx
mov rax,2
mov rbx,10

mul rbx

pop rdx
```

Basically, I am preserving the register on the stack prior to the `mul` instruction that messes with it ... then popping it back afterwards (because I don't care about the value in `rdx` .. I want it to be what I want it to be).

My question is: Is this okay to do? Is it common? I haven't been doing this for very long .. but it feels a bit strange.

I could instead resort to using local variables for some of my computations instead of registers .. that would probably solve the issue without resorting to pushing it onto the stack for this short period of time .. but the question still stands.

Bonus question: Is there somewhere that has full coverage of what these instructions do in a 64-bit context? I can't seem to find a reference that actually tells me in plain English what is happening to the `rdx` register after the `mul` instruction.

Comment: An n x n multiply has a 2n result.  These kind of push/pops is the way to tell that machine code was written by a human instead of a machine :)  It looks like an innocent way to solve a problem, it is not.  Stack memory access has a 3 cycle latency.  A machine will look for a way to store the value in another register, like r9-r15 or xmm0-15.  Or consider the possibility to use a SIMD instruction so you get 4 multiplies at the same time :)

Comment: Yeah, this is what my tiny brain is now realizing :) I was trying to stay away from the extra registers (`r9`, etc), so that I could port this easily enough to 32 bit sometime down the road. I see that there are multiple reasons why this is probably not a good idea - so I will re-visit my register usage. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there somewhere that has full coverage of what these instructions do in a 64-bit context? I can't seem to find a reference that actually tells me in plain English what is happening to the rdx register after the mul instruction

[Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) puts it pretty clearly:

```
MUL r/m64   Unsigned multiply (RDX:RAX ← RAX ∗ r/m64).
```

That is, `RDX` will hold the most significant 64 bits of the product.

As for your main question; use a different register if you can. If you can't, then you'll need to back up `RDX`'s value somehow, and using the stack is a simple way of doing so.

Comment: Thanks. This might sound stupid, but I couldn't find the relevant part of the manual last night :/ Thanks for the explanation. Sometimes you just need someone to point you in the obvious direction!

Answer (score 2):

Pushing/popping is totally justified in this case.

Why don't you use `imul rax,rbx` or even `imul rax,10`? These don't **mess** with RDX at all.

Comment: Or `lea rax, [rax + rax * 4] \ shl rax`

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realise I could do that. I'll have a play with this also.

Answer (score 2):

It's not always OK. For example on win64, random pushes and pops that are not in the prolog or epilog defeat unwinding, things would go very wrong if an exception happened before the stack pointer is back to normal.

It's not really necessary in this case though, since you can multiply without affecting `rdx`.

Comment: Thanks for the Windows mention - something I didn't even consider! I have a lot to learn it seems :)